# Pentaho: Invalid conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP

Tags: date, pentaho

I transferred a DATE value from **Informix** database to **Redbrick** database without any processing. But "Insert/Update" step failed with the error:

```
Invalid conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP
```

Both columns in source and target databases are of type DATE.
I thought that it might be a format issue, so I used a "Select values" step to set the date format explicitely. But it didn't help.

Below is the full stack:

```
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Error in step, asking everyone to stop because of:
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - 
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 3
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - ** Error ** (11002) [Red Brick Warehouse JDBC Driver] : Column 4 : Invalid conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP.
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - 
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - 
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2764)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2734)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getLookup(Database.java:3103)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getLookup(Database.java:3093)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getLookup(Database.java:3089)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.insertupdate.InsertUpdate.lookupValues(InsertUpdate.java:89)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.insertupdate.InsertUpdate.processRow(InsertUpdate.java:299)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 3
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - ** Error ** (11002) [Red Brick Warehouse JDBC Driver] : Column 4 : Invalid conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP.
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - 
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getValueFromResultSet(ValueMetaBase.java:5310)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.BaseDatabaseMeta.getValueFromResultSet(BaseDatabaseMeta.java:2107)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.getValueFromResultSet(DatabaseMeta.java:2982)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2756)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    ... 8 more
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ** Error ** (11002) [Red Brick Warehouse JDBC Driver] : Column 4 : Invalid conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP.
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at redbrick.utils.ErrorHandlers.errorHandler(ErrorHandlers.java:44)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at redbrick.utils.ErrorHandlers.errorHandler(ErrorHandlers.java:29)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at redbrick.jdbc.RBWResultSet.errorHandler(RBWResultSet.java:3952)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at redbrick.jdbc.RBWResultSet.getTimestamp(RBWResultSet.java:2993)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getValueFromResultSet(ValueMetaBase.java:5292)
2019/06/14 16:48:39 - Insert / update LOAD_CONTR.0 -    ... 11 more
```

What could be a problem? Wrong date format? If so, what query do I have to run to get the date format of both databases?

I've looked at the DDL. The column type is DATE:

```
create table ... (
...
DATE_FIRST DATE,
DATE_LAST DATE,
...
```

Comment: From the error, it looks like the Insert/Update is failing when retrieving the row from Redbrick for comparing/updating. It might be forcing a conversion to timestamp if the incoming row metadata says the date is a timestamp. Check the input fields to verify that it is really date format.

Comment: @Cyrus how to check it?

Comment: Right-click the Insert/Update step and then click "Input Fields..."

Comment: @Cyrus I've checked the type in that dialog. It's date.